# How to combine turtle_owned variables up to a maximum number of turtles?

Tags: netlogo, agent

*EDIT - The issue has been resolved by updating my Netlogo version from 6.0.3 to 6.1.0 to use primitive "up-to-n-of" *

In my Netlogo program, turtles (namely carbs) own a variable called mass. The setup procedure creates 10 turtles with variable mass from 1 to 3. The to-go procedure asks BIG turtles to find other turtle (target) which mass is less than 2, obtain the mass of the "target", and kill the target. At first, using primitive "up-to-n-of" gave me error in the older Netlogo version. Now, I am using the primitive "up-to-n-of" and "other" to avoid 2 turtles killing the same "target" in a newer Netlogo version.

For example, my model set ups random:
[image]

My previous model used primitive "one-of" and in one tick obtained,
[image]

Now, my model identifies 2 or more carbs with mass < 2 per tick.
For example, if carbs can identify 2 other carbs with the same set up the results would be:

| Turtles | Carbs_mass |
| --- | --- |
| Carb_0 kills carb_9 and carb_8 | gets carbs_mass 5 |
| Carb_1 kills carb_7 and carb_6 | gets carbs_mass 5 |
| Carb_2 | keeps carbs_mass 1 |
| Carb_3 | keeps carbs_mass 1 |
| Carb_4 | keeps carbs_mass 1 |
| Carb_5 | keeps carbs_mass 1 |
| Total mass | 14 |

Any comments or suggestions on this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
Breed [carbs carb]

carbs-own [carbs_mass]


Globals
[time]

to setup
  clear-all
  set time 0

 ;;;CARBS;;;

  set-default-shape carbs "circle"
  Create-carbs (10)
  [
    set color white
    set size 1.5
    set carbs_mass (1 + random-float 2)
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if not any? turtles [stop]

   ask carbs
  [combine_carbs]

  set time time + 1

  tick

  if (time = 1) [stop]
end


to combine_carbs
  if carbs_mass > 2
  [
  let target up-to-n-of 2 other carbs with
   [carbs_mass < 2]
  if target != nobody
  [set carbs_mass carbs_mass + sum ([carbs_mass] of target)
    ask target [die]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Is this is a question about how indivisible and "atomic"  combine_carbs is?   Because if it is atomic,  regardless how many carbs are busy doing this in parallel two will never pick the same target because the first one to find it will kill it right after identifying it.     I could think that step one might be to create a link to one of the other carbs which had mass less than 2 AND had no links,  which might be more atomic / less likely to be interleaved.  But you also ask CARBS to do this, not BIG carbs,  so the TARGET of one step that didn't kill it might be busy targeting others.

Comment: I don't know if Netlogo has an atomic test-and-set type command.  Anyone know?

Comment: Dear Wade Schuette, thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate on what “atomic” means? Also, I just added an example of the current and desired results in my question. Could you please check and see if links are still recommended? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Dear all, primitive "up-to-n-of" works in Netlogo version 6.1.0 not in version 6.0.3. Thanks!

Comment: @WadeSchuette The NetLogo language is single-threaded; it has no support for concurrency or parallelism of any kind. So it follows from that that there isn't anything like atomic-test-and-set.

Comment: @SethTisue -- well,   Behavior Space allows for multiple cores to run in parallel so there is sort of concurrency!

Comment: Mmm hmm, that's why I said "the NetLogo language". BehaviorSpace is outside of the language.

Answer (score 0):

To use `up-to-n-of`, you'll need to be using NetLogo 6.1 or higher. It doesn't exist in 6.0.